# Problems while printing a PDF from the Web-Browser embedded PDF viewer by hitting ctrl+p

Tags: pdf, browser, printing, keyboard-shortcuts

Folks,
I'm facing a problem that seem so simple yet unsolvable. I did a lot of research on this topic, but wasn't able to come up with an apropriate solution.
From within my Angular application, a PDF is download from one of my REST service, a  Blob URL is generated from it (of cause a SafeResourceURL) and then embedded within one of my components in an object like so:

```html
<object
    [data]="<BLOB URL's content goes here>"
    type="application/pdf"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
  ></object>
```

This object is thus contained in a full fledged HTML page.

As expected, the web browsers embedded PDF viewer opens and displays the PDF. By clicking the pdf viewers print button, a print preview (and physical print out) is generated with no errors.
The enduser now expects to also trigger the PDF viewers print by hitting ctrl+p but now strange yet explainable things happen, no matter which browser I use:

1. After the PDF is displayed, hit ctrl+p without any further ado

| Expected result | Actual result |
| --- | --- |
| A printed PDF the same way as if the User clicked the print button | A printed PDF surrounded by the PDF viewers gray modal dialog border. |

2. After the PDF is displayed, click on the gray modal dialog border of the PDF viewer, then hit ctrl+p

| Expected result | Actual result |
| --- | --- |
| A printed PDF the same way as if the User clicked the print button | A blank page gets printed |

3. After the PDF is displayed, mark some of PDF's text, then hit ctrl+p

That again leads to an expected print.

My assumption is, that by embedding the PDF in an  element, the browser doen't redirect the ctrl+p to the PDF viewer, but tries to print the whole HTML page instead, which is a normal yet undesirable behaviour.

None of the problems happen, if a PDF is downloaded directly or if the BLOB URL is the source of a new browser tab, sice in this scenario, there will be no surrounding HTML page, that interfers with ctrl+p

I think that my usecase in't that uncommon, so my question is:
Since first clicking the PDF document displayed within the PDF viewer to trigger a print is not an option, is there (if any) an elegant and easy way to ship around these problems.

P.s.: I already tried the common ways of loading the PDF into an iframe and trigger the print of its content programmatically, but without any luck.

I even tried the the objectpdf utility, to accomplish my goal, but the seem to suffer from the same problem, if you check out their embedded examples.

I'm aware of a question here on stack overflow, that addresses the same topic, but the answer to this question is rather old (2012) which in computer science is eons away.

I really hope for some advise from you.

Comment: Hi @KJ, first of all, thanks for your answer, but I think that you didn't get the point. As I stated in the topic, it's all about a Web-Browser's embedded PDF viewer, and the print out containing parts of the HTML structure, that surrounds the embedded PDF document. That additional HTML is the main problen, that I want to get rid of.

Comment: Nope, the PDF is already transfered and displayed inside a users Web-Browser as I stated above. There's neither an external binary application incorporated in the process nor do I long to print something remotely. Lets break it down to a simpler question. If I have a PDF embedded inside an HTML page. How can I print just the PDF document instead of the whole HTML page, when hitting ctrl+p

Answer (score 0):

This is common browser / embed framed object behaviour the two are independent and responsible only for their own print areas.

HTML print() guide

> "If the printing dialog is blocked by a Document's sandbox, then neither the beforeprint nor afterprint events will be fired."

The idea is there is no JS ability to action anything other than throw up the print dialog for the current html page.

PDF has 2 pages to print , HTML only has one outside the frame.

[image]

Chromium (Edge) may fare better as it can add a screenshot of PDF object area:-

[image]